# How to apply filter on a column (with datatype array (of strings)) on a PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("u1", ['a', 'b']),
    ("u2", ['c', 'b']),
    ("u3", ['a', 'b']),

    ],
    ['user_id', 'features'])

print(df.printSchema())
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

None
+-------+--------+
|user_id|features|
+-------+--------+
|u1     |[a, b]  |
|u2     |[c, b]  |
|u3     |[a, b]  |
+-------+--------+
```

I only want to keep the keeps with column named **features** [a, b]. Since this column is an array of strings, simple filter can not be used.

How can I achieve this?

Expected output:

```
+-------+--------+
|user_id|features|
+-------+--------+
|u1     |[a, b]  |
|u3     |[a, b]  |
+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array(lit(...))`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.filter(F.array_sort(F.col('features')) == F.array_sort(F.array(F.lit('a'), F.lit('b'))))

df2.show()
+-------+--------+
|user_id|features|
+-------+--------+
|     u1|  [a, b]|
|     u3|  [a, b]|
+-------+--------+
```

Comment: how can I pass 'a' and 'b' in array_contains? I want a general solution which would let me keep only rows with only 'a' and 'b' in the features column.

Comment: the updated answer is better. but it would miss out on the cases where the feature column is [b, a]. I want all the rows with features column having 'a' and 'b' and nothing else. order of a and b should not matter.

Comment: i think it would be even better to apply F.array_sort on the RHS on the equality. that way we do not necessarily have to write a and b in that order